# How do I properly save to my mongoDB collections using mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

hope all is well!  I am new to this and I had a question, I have this problem with this post method to mongoDB using Mongoose, Express, its not going into the collections but I am connected to the database correctly because I see MongoDB database connection established successfully in the terminal but I got this 404 error in the console of the application with the actual data from the form I am trying to put in my exercises collection in atlas. It's been driving me nuts because I have been googling and reading for a while and their docs but couldn't connect the pieces correctly, If there is anyway someone can help that would be greatly appreciated.

```js
   <form action="/api/form" method="POST" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

    onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                axios
                .post('/api/form', values, actions)
                .then(response => {
                  console.log(response);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                  console.log(error.response);
                });
                console.log({ values, actions });
                alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
                actions.setSubmitting(false);
              }, 400);
            }}

const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const Exercise = require("./models/routes.model");
require("dotenv").config();
​
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();
​
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  })
);
​
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
​
const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true });
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', (error) => console.error(error))
db.once("open", () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
});
​
app.use(require('./routes/routes'));
app.post("/api/form", async (req, res) => {
  const firstName =   req.body.firstName;
  const middleName =  req.body.middleName;
  const lastName =  req.body.lastName;
  const phone =  Number(req.body.phone);
  const email =  req.body.email;
  const confirmEmail =  req.body.confirmEmail;
  const comments =  req.body.comments;
  const StreetAddress =  req.body.StreetAddress;
  const unit =  req.body.unit;
  const state =  req.body.state;
  const city =  req.body.city;
  const zip =  req.body.zip;
  const typeOfDegree =  req.body.typeOfDegree;
  const degreeAttained =  req.body.degreeAttained;
  const educationalInstitution =  req.body.educationalInstitution;
  const otherInformation =  req.body.otherInformation;
​
  const newExercise =  new Exercise({
    firstName,
    middleName,
    lastName,
    phone,
    email,
    confirmEmail,
    comments,
    StreetAddress,
    unit,
    state,
    city,
    zip,
    typeOfDegree,
    degreeAttained,
    educationalInstitution,
    otherInformation
  });
  console.log(Exercises);
  newExercise.save()
    .then(() => res.json('Email added to DB!'))
    .catch(err => res.json('Error: ' + err));
});
​
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // get information from html forms
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  // Exprees will serve up production assets
  app.use(express.static("/app/index.html"));
​
  // Express serve up index.html file if it doesn't recognize route
  const path = require("path");
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve("/app/index.html"));
  });
}
​
// Listen to whatever port above.
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Our app is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
Collapse
```

Comment: If you're getting a 404 you shouldn't be worried about mongo. It sounds like you are not hitting the route.

Comment: So I am using React & my onSubmit is like so 

`axios
                    .post('/form', values, actions) // no try/catch here
                    .then(response => {
                      console.log(response);
                    })`
and my server.js has the post going to form too.

`app.post("/form", async (req, res) => {`
@MarkMeyer

Comment: ``` <form action="/api/form" method="POST" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>```

Shouldn't it hit if the action is `action="/api/form" ` and `.post("/api/form", values)` in the onSubmit. As well as the backend `app.post("/api/form", async (req, res) => {` ???

Comment: Fixed it: so for anyone in the future runs into this issue, remember when you set up your server file and it opens up on lets say port `http://localhost:3030/` and your React app is on `http://localhost:3000/` you have to post on the front end like so

     ` axios
        .post("http://localhost:3030/api/form", values, actions) // no try/catch here
        .then(response => {console.log(response);   })`

Because thats where your server is listening to.